# regex to remove zeros at beginning of string but not for decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex to implement in javascript that removes any 0 at the begginin of a string if is an integer.

```
 0 => ''
 0000 => ''
 001 => 1
 0.11 => 0.11
 0000.11 => 0.11
 11000 => 11000
```

I've tried to accomplish this USING REGEX, but not able yet.

Comment: Show us your attempts pls

Comment: "0000.11 => 0.11" contradicts "removes any 0 at the begginin of a string if is an integer."

Comment: if ( 0.11 == .11  ) log('value the same')

Answer (score 4):

Something like so should work: `^0+(?!\.)`. An example of the expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/jW1zX9/1).

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what ?! does?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa: The `?!` is called *Negative Look Ahead*, and it essentially looks at the next character(s) and ensures that they are not there. In this case, it ensures that when reading a `0`, it ensures that the following character is not a `.`. When it finds a `0` which has a `.` that preceeds it, it stops.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for Regex, but how about using `parseFloat`?

```
var str = (parseFloat("0000.11") || '').toString();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuygsrry/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

Find: `^0+([.1-9])`
Replace `$1`

Answer (score 0):

Arnold,

I use the below regex to remove leading zeros from the number:

```
var str = str.replace(/(^| )(0+)/g, "");
```

It looks for zero character in quantity of one and more, at the line beginning or after space.

Here is [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pS4kN2/1)